# bad array subscript in if statement

Tags: arrays, syntax-error, subscript

I have a script where I'm creating a couple of a couple of command line arguments to pass in (file and output).  The script appears to be working as I can successfully pass files into the script and parse them with the "-f" flag, but I noticed I'm getting the following error (on this line in the code below: if [[ -n ${variables[$argument_label]} ]]):

line 29: variables: bad array subscript

```
# declaring a couple of associative arrays
declare -A arguments=();
declare -A variables=();

# declaring an index integer
declare -i index=1;

variables["-o"]="output";
variables["--output"]="output";
variables["-f"]="file";
variables["--file"]="file";

# $@ here represents all arguments passed in
for i in "$@"
do
  arguments[$index]=$i;
  prev_index="$(expr $index - 1)";

  # this if block does something akin to "where $i contains ="
  # "%=*" here strips out everything from the = to the end of the argument leaving only the label
  if [[ $i == *"="* ]]
    then argument_label=${i%=*}
    else argument_label=${arguments[$prev_index]}
  fi

  # this if block only evaluates to true if the argument label exists in the variables array
  if [[ -n ${variables[$argument_label]} ]]
    then
        # dynamically creating variables names using declare
        # "#$argument_label=" here strips out the label leaving only the value
        if [[ $i == *"="* ]]
            then declare ${variables[$argument_label]}=${i#$argument_label=}
            else declare ${variables[$argument_label]}=${arguments[$index]}
        fi
  fi

  index=index+1;
done;
```

Any ideas or insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding quotes?

if [[ -n "${variables[$argument_label]}" ]]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).